# What does replace(/\n/g, "something") mean?

Tags: javascript

I've come across this code many times and have never figured out what it means

```
/\n/g
```

Comment: It is a regular expression , which matches all the  `\n`(newline characters)

Comment: It's a regex expression telling to replace `\n` i.e newline with string `something` globally.

Comment: Thanks, but what does the `g` do?

Comment: `g` is identifier telling to perform the match globally i.e. find all matches rather than stopping after the first match

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will replace all new line character in your string with "something" . i.e

```
var str="Hi\nHello";
console.log(str);
```

Output:

Hi

Hello

```
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,"and"));
```

Output:

HiandHello

```
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,""));
```

Output:

HiHello