# Where should we store APNs p8 key on web server?

Tags: laravel, private-key

I have Laravel running on EC2 instance and I have a `.p8` for APNs. Everything is working fine, but I’m wondering what the convention is regarding best location for `.p8` files. It doesn’t feel right to just drop them in the base path of the Laravel project.

This seems like a fairly obvious question, but searching around I haven’t found any recommendations regarding best practices on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the `.p8` file or just the certificate contents - you could just put it in as an environment variable. That way it's kept separate from your code and specific to the environment it's being used.

Comment: Yep, that’s certainly an option. Thanks.

Comment: How do you specify the .p8 PRIVATE KEY contents as a ENV var since it is multi-line and in between -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- & -----END PRIVATE KEY-----?

Comment: @JakeSmith You can use `\n` at the start of each of the new lines. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459528/using-private-key-in-a-env-file).