# How to prevent a new line character (\n) of a string from being the part of the string and not doing its job in python?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Looking for help solving an issue. I have stored a public key in .env file, public key is having \n in it  and for .env i have used python dcouple but when I am using the environment variable in a function then \n is not doing its job but it is becoming the part of the string.

```
.env
KEY=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nAp4k567H7J7\nG2rtJH\nLok1FG3\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n

utility.py
var = data(KEY=config('KEY'))
print(config('KEY')) #it is not giving the desired result its printing below result
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nAp4k567H7J7\nG2rtJH\nLok1FG3\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n

but i need this string to be like this when used in utility.py
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
Ap4k567H7J7
G2rtJH
Lok1FG3
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the way you get it from the file. I have no idea why, but I think, when you get some string from this file, your library, or python, or something else, replaces `'\n'` with `'\\n'` so you will not see the expecting output anyway.
The solution that I can suggest is to take your string and do this stuff:

```
key = config('KEY')
key = key.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

And so you can print `key` as you wanted. Maybe it is not perfect, but it's going to work.

Answer (score 1):

`.env` files and libraries that read them, generally, do not support newlines. It appears your env file contains escaped newlines; a *literal* `\n` in place of a newline.

In this case, you must unescape the newline characters in the file.

```py
key_data = config('KEY')
key = key_data.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

Additional reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55459738/5747944

You may also consider a different mechanism for storing and retrieving the public key. For example, you may store the system *path* to the key file in the environment variable and read it from disk, instead.

So in your .env

```
PUBLIC_KEY_FILE=/path/to/key.pub
```

Then in code:

```py
key_file_path = config('PUBLIC_KEY_FILE')
with open(key_file_path) as f:
    key = f.read()
```